# PLS-00103, in Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
create or replace TRIGGER log_worlds BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON worlds
DECLARE
ac VARCHAR2(50);
tab VARCHAR2(50);
world VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
IF UPDATING THEN
ac:='Aktualizacja';
END IF;
IF INSERTING THEN
ac:='Nowe';
END IF;
tab:='WORLDS';
world:='world_';
world:=world||cast(NEW_WORLD.NEXTVAL as VARCHAR2(10));
INSERT INTO log(ACTION_DATE,ACTION,TAB_NAME,ADDED_WORLD) VALUES(SYSDATE,ac,tab,world);
INSERT INTO worlds(WORLD_NAME) VALUES(world);
END;
```

Can someone help me with this,error information is about line 14?  This trigger is supposed to add new values to the log table and to change the primary key value of the worlds table when my APEX application issues DML against the table.

Comment: Indentation is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

the error you get suggests some syntax error in your code which I can't immediately find. However I would expect another error becuase Oracle won't allow you do execute DML statements (select, insert, update, delete) inside of a trigger on the same table as the trigger is on. Your trigger is on table worlds, so you are not allowed to insert a record into table worlds inside the trigger.

Comment: Thanks. But now how i can create trigger ,or something else, to insert a primary key to world table. My primary key in this table is WOLD_NAME which is VARCHAR2 type?

Comment: But it's a statement level trigger, not a row level trigger, so DML should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate syntax error is that assuming `NEW_WORLD` is a sequence you've created, you would need to do something like

```
SELECT world ||
         cast( new_world.nextval as varchar2(10) )
  INTO world
  FROM dual;
```

rather than directly referencing the sequence in your `CAST`.

It's far from clear to me what your trigger is supposed to be doing though.  It is, at a minimum, going to generate an infinite loop.  Every `INSERT` on `WORLDS` is going to cause the trigger to fire which will generate an `INSERT` on `WORLDS` which will cause the trigger to fire, etc.  Oracle will eventually raise an error when you exceed the maximum recursion depth.  Perhaps you intended this to be a row-level trigger rather than a statement-level trigger that changed the value of `:new.world_name`?  If that's the case, you'd probably want something like

```
create or replace TRIGGER log_worlds 
  BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON worlds
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  ac VARCHAR2(50);
  tab VARCHAR2(50);
  world VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  IF UPDATING THEN
    ac:='Aktualizacja';
  END IF;
  IF INSERTING THEN
    ac:='Nowe';
  END IF;
  tab:='WORLDS';
  world:='world_';
  select world || cast(new_world.nextval as varchar2(10)
    into world
    from dual;
  INSERT INTO log(ACTION_DATE,ACTION,TAB_NAME,ADDED_WORLD) 
    VALUES(SYSDATE,ac,tab,world);
  :new.world_name := world;
END;
```

This assumes that `world_name` is not actually the primary key.  If `world_name` is the primary key then it would make no sense to modify the primary key value when a row is updated-- you would only want to potentially assign the primary key if you are doing an `INSERT`.

Comment: The direct usage of .nextval in an assignment does work in 11.2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Direct assignment does work in 11.2.  Directly using `to_char` works (as you suggested).  Directly using `cast`, however, does not.

Comment: Yes that is true i missed this thanks. This trigger i suppos to add new data to LOG table (which is simple log when were changes in table worlds) and aslo adds a new priamry key to date that were added using application

Comment: @user1415018 - Then it sounds like you want a row-level trigger that changes `:new.world_name`.  If `world_name` is the primary key, though, I can't quite understand why you'd want to change the primary key whenever the row is updated.  That sort of defeats the purpose of a primary key

Answer (score 1):

I think it's this line here:

```
world:=world||cast(NEW_WORLD.NEXTVAL as VARCHAR2(10));
```

If you replace it with:

```
world := world||to_char(NEW_WORLD.NEXTVAL);
```

it should work.

Btw: directly using a `nextval` call in an assignment does not work on versions prior to 11.x (not sure about the value of x here).

In 10.x you would need to declare a variable and then use:

```
SELECT to_char(new_world.nextval)
   into world_num;
world := world || world_num;
```